# Flutter - underline or paint words text to speech (TTS)

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech, underline

I have a flutter program that translates from text to speech, but I have a question, how to underline what it says? that is to say that each word that is said is underlined or painted, I hope someone can help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're getting a progress callback during the TTS that has begin and end values.  Just break the text into three parts (part before begin, part between begin and end, and part after end), and assign them into three TextSpan with the appropriate annotation.

Answer (score 0):

This discussion should assist you: https://github.com/dlutton/flutter_tts/discussions/193
Below is the code from the gist provided in that discussion:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

enum TtsState { playing, stopped, paused, continued }

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late FlutterTts flutterTts;
  dynamic languages;
  String? language;
  double volume = 0.5;
  double pitch = 1.0;
  double rate = 0.5;
  bool isCurrentLanguageInstalled = false;
  int start = 0;
  int end = 0;

  String? _newVoiceText;

  TtsState ttsState = TtsState.stopped;

  get isPlaying => ttsState == TtsState.playing;
  get isStopped => ttsState == TtsState.stopped;
  get isPaused => ttsState == TtsState.paused;
  get isContinued => ttsState == TtsState.continued;

  bool get isIOS => !kIsWeb && Platform.isIOS;
  bool get isAndroid => !kIsWeb && Platform.isAndroid;
  bool get isWeb => kIsWeb;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    initTts();
  }

  initTts() {
    flutterTts = FlutterTts();

    _getLanguages();

    if (isAndroid) {
      _getEngines();
    }

    flutterTts.setStartHandler(() {
      setState(() {
        print("Playing");
        ttsState = TtsState.playing;
      });
    });

    flutterTts.setCompletionHandler(() {
      setState(() {
        print("Complete");
        ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
      });
    });

    flutterTts.setCancelHandler(() {
      setState(() {
        print("Cancel");
        ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
      });
    });

    if (isWeb || isIOS) {
      flutterTts.setPauseHandler(() {
        setState(() {
          print("Paused");
          ttsState = TtsState.paused;
        });
      });

      flutterTts.setContinueHandler(() {
        setState(() {
          print("Continued");
          ttsState = TtsState.continued;
        });
      });
    }

    flutterTts.setErrorHandler((msg) {
      setState(() {
        print("error: $msg");
        ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
      });
    });

    flutterTts.setProgressHandler(
        (String text, int startOffset, int endOffset, String word) {
      setState(() {
        start = startOffset;
        end = endOffset;
      });
    });
  }

  Future _getLanguages() async {
    languages = await flutterTts.getLanguages;
    if (languages != null) setState(() => languages);
  }

  Future _getEngines() async {
    var engines = await flutterTts.getEngines;
    if (engines != null) {
      for (dynamic engine in engines) {
        print(engine);
      }
    }
  }

  Future _speak() async {
    await flutterTts.setVolume(volume);
    await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(rate);
    await flutterTts.setPitch(pitch);

    if (_newVoiceText != null) {
      await flutterTts.awaitSpeakCompletion(true);
      await flutterTts.speak(_newVoiceText!);
    }
  }

  Future _stop() async {
    var result = await flutterTts.stop();
    if (result == 1) setState(() => ttsState = TtsState.stopped);
  }

  Future _pause() async {
    var result = await flutterTts.pause();
    if (result == 1) setState(() => ttsState = TtsState.paused);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    flutterTts.stop();
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getLanguageDropDownMenuItems() {
    var items = <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[];
    for (dynamic type in languages) {
      items.add(DropdownMenuItem(value: type as String, child: Text(type)));
    }
    return items;
  }

  void changedLanguageDropDownItem(String? selectedType) {
    setState(() {
      language = selectedType;
      flutterTts.setLanguage(language!);
      if (isAndroid) {
        flutterTts
            .isLanguageInstalled(language!)
            .then((value) => isCurrentLanguageInstalled = (value as bool));
      }
    });
  }

  void _onChange(String text) {
    setState(() {
      _newVoiceText = text;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Flutter TTS'),
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(children: [
                  _inputSection(),
                  ttsState == TtsState.playing
                      ? _textFromInput(start, end)
                      : Text(""),
                  _btnSection(),
                  languages != null ? _languageDropDownSection() : Text(""),
                  _buildSliders()
                ]))));
  }

  Widget _inputSection() => Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
      child: TextField(
        onChanged: (String value) {
          _onChange(value);
          start = 0;
          end = value.length;
        },
      ));

  Widget _textFromInput(int start, int end) => Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
      child: RichText(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
              text: _newVoiceText != null && start != 0
                  ? _newVoiceText!.substring(0, start)
                  : "",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          TextSpan(
              text: _newVoiceText != null
                  ? _newVoiceText!.substring(start, end)
                  : "",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          TextSpan(
              text: _newVoiceText != null ? _newVoiceText!.substring(end) : "",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        ]),
      ));

  Widget _btnSection() {
    if (isAndroid) {
      return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
          child:
              Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, children: [
            _buildButtonColumn(Colors.green, Colors.greenAccent,
                Icons.play_arrow, 'PLAY', _speak),
            _buildButtonColumn(
                Colors.red, Colors.redAccent, Icons.stop, 'STOP', _stop),
          ]));
    } else {
      return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
          child:
              Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, children: [
            _buildButtonColumn(Colors.green, Colors.greenAccent,
                Icons.play_arrow, 'PLAY', _speak),
            _buildButtonColumn(
                Colors.red, Colors.redAccent, Icons.stop, 'STOP', _stop),
            _buildButtonColumn(
                Colors.blue, Colors.blueAccent, Icons.pause, 'PAUSE', _pause),
          ]));
    }
  }

  Widget _languageDropDownSection() => Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
      child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
        DropdownButton(
          value: language,
          items: getLanguageDropDownMenuItems(),
          onChanged: changedLanguageDropDownItem,
        ),
        Visibility(
          visible: isAndroid,
          child: Text("Is installed: $isCurrentLanguageInstalled"),
        ),
      ]));

  Column _buildButtonColumn(Color color, Color splashColor, IconData icon,
      String label, Function func) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(icon),
              color: color,
              splashColor: splashColor,
              onPressed: () => func()),
          Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Text(label,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: color)))
        ]);
  }

  Widget _buildSliders() {
    return Column(
      children: [_volume(), _pitch(), _rate()],
    );
  }

  Widget _volume() {
    return Slider(
        value: volume,
        onChanged: (newVolume) {
          setState(() => volume = newVolume);
        },
        min: 0.0,
        max: 1.0,
        divisions: 10,
        label: "Volume: $volume");
  }

  Widget _pitch() {
    return Slider(
      value: pitch,
      onChanged: (newPitch) {
        setState(() => pitch = newPitch);
      },
      min: 0.5,
      max: 2.0,
      divisions: 15,
      label: "Pitch: $pitch",
      activeColor: Colors.red,
    );
  }

  Widget _rate() {
    return Slider(
      value: rate,
      onChanged: (newRate) {
        setState(() => rate = newRate);
      },
      min: 0.0,
      max: 1.0,
      divisions: 10,
      label: "Rate: $rate",
      activeColor: Colors.green,
    );
  }
}
```